# Infinite loop when using useLazyQuery in React + Apollo/GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo

My code so far looks something like this:

```
const { ID } = useParams();
const [getObjects, {loading, data}] = useLazyQuery(GET_OBJECTS_BY_ID);

const objectWithID = props.data.find(datum => datum._id == ID);
if (objectWithID.conditional) {
    getObjects({variables: {objectIds: objectWithID.subObjects}});
    //Do a bunch of other stuff including a separate render
}
else {...}
```

What I'm essentially doing is finding an object with the specified `ID` first, and then querying for its subObjects. I want to first find the `objectWithID` variable before querying, and then based on one of its parameters, conditionally use its value, hence I think `useLazyQuery` helps to achieve this. However, this causes an infinite loop: for some reason it's being called an infinite number of times, crashing my webpage. Am I using `useLazyQuery` incorrectly? How could I prevent this   infinite loop?

Comment: you can use useQuery directly if the id is already existent ( no need to use useLazy query in your case)

Comment: I was thinking that, but then depending on the conditional on objectWithID, I render something different, so that conditional causes an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're executing the query inside the render method, meaning it'll just keep firing. Instead, consider using a `useEffect` hook:

```
const { ID } = useParams();
const [getObjects, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_OBJECTS_BY_ID);

const objectWithID = useMemo(() => {
  return props.data.find((datum) => datum._id == ID);
}, [props.data, ID]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (objectWithID.conditional) {
    getObjects({ variables: { objectIds: objectWithID.subObjects } });
  }
}, [getObjects, objectWithID]);

return objectWithID.conditional ? (
  <>Render one thing</>
) : (
  <>Render the other thing</>
);
```

Note that I also threw in a `useMemo` hook to memoize the `objectWithID` value so it only changes when `props.data` or `ID` changes.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to include something crucial, which I was editing as you typed your response. Based on the conditional, I would define entirely different callbacks and render something different, so I'm not sure of useEffect could still be used to that end.

Comment: You could still key your render below off of `objectWithID.conditional` but use the effect to manage the data fetching